# Rails, Paperclip not validating content type "application/octet-stream"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload files of the mime-type "application/octet-stream", but they aren't validating properly.

In the controller, when I call `replay.save!`, I get the following error:

```
Validation failed: r_file has contents that are not what they are reported to be, r_file is invalid, r_file content type is invalid
```

Here is the model:

```
class Replay < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :r_file
    validates_attachment_content_type :r_file, content_type: { content_type: "application/octet-stream" }
end
```

and the create method in the replay controller:

```
def create
    @replay = Replay.new(replay_params)
    if @replay.save
        # This never runs because it won't validate.
        puts "REPLAY SAVED."
        redirect_to @replay
    else
        puts "REPLAY NOT SAVED."
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I checked the mime-type of the file I'm trying to upload, and it is definitely of type `"application/octet-stream"`. Is Paperclip just reading the file type incorrectly?

EDIT:

Here is the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161203161351) do

  create_table "replays", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "map"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "r_file_file_name"
    t.string   "r_file_content_type"
    t.integer  "r_file_file_size"
    t.datetime "r_file_updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Paperclip doesn't use mime type gem to figure the file type it uses `file` check https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1530

Comment: It might be that file is returning something different like `application/x-bittorrent` but mime type treat it as `octet-stream`

Comment: Would the file type not be the same either way? I just tried validating using `application/x-bittorrent` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try allowing all `application/*` and then check what paperclip read that file

Comment: No it would fail the type validation if it's not a match even if the os sees them the same

Comment: It didn't even validate using `application/*`.

Comment: @ArunKumar that reduced the error so something a little more specific. New error: `Validation failed: r_file has contents that are not what they are reported to be`

Comment: @JoshArts After changing the validation?

Comment: This error is responding to content type spoofing... in a nutshell renaming .mp3 file to .txt and uploading it as txt file

Comment: That makes sense since my files are of type .replay , is there a way around this?

Comment: @ArunKumar yes, after changing the validation. I can also confirm that paperclip is reading the type as "application/octet-stream", as that's what it says in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Validate all formats in rails Video/Image

```
validates_attachment_content_type :media,
      content_type: [
        'image/jpg',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/x-png',
        'video/avi',
        'video/mov',
        'video/mp4',
        'video/x-flv',
        'video/3gpp',
        'video/quicktime',
        'video/x-msvideo',
        'video/x-ms-wmv',
        'flv-application/octet-stream',
        'application/octet-stream',
        'video/x-flv',
        'video/mpeg',
        'video/mpeg4',
        'video/x-la-asf',
        'video/x-ms-asf'
      ],
        :message => 'file type is not allowed'
```